# How to extract the information from XML beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a list of XML beautifulsoap tag elements as:

```
[
 <Entry>
    <EffectiveDate>
    <DateFormattedForTHForm>07/01/2022</DateFormattedForTHForm>
    </EffectiveDate>
    <ExpirationDate>
    <DateFormattedForTHForm>07/01/2023</DateFormattedForTHForm>
    </ExpirationDate>
    <FormDescription>Notification Of Settlement</FormDescription>
    <FormNumber>WC 99 06 04</FormNumber>
 </Entry>,
 
 <Entry>
 <AccountContactRole>
 <AccountContact>
    <Contact>
    <DisplayName>Mallesham Yamulla</DisplayName>
    <FEINOrSSN>123-45-6789</FEINOrSSN>
    <formsMaskedSSN_and_NoMaskFEIN>**-***-8834</formsMaskedSSN_and_NoMaskFEIN>
    <PrimaryAddress>
    <AddressLine1>A</AddressLine1>
    <AddressLine123>B</AddressLine123>
    <CityStateZip>ENID, OK 73703</CityStateZip>
    <Country>IND</Country>
    <AddressLine2 xsi:nil="true"/>
    <AddressLine3 xsi:nil="true"/>
    </PrimaryAddress>
    </Contact>
    </AccountContact>
    </AccountContactRole>
 </Entry>
 
 ]
```

Here I would like to loop through the list of entry xml elements, get a tag name and its contained information's, if any of tag is empty and its information is also empty it should be ignored.

From first entry the below tag information is required to be extracted as they hold on information.

```
[<DateFormattedForTHForm>07/01/2022</DateFormattedForTHForm>,
<DateFormattedForTHForm>07/01/2023</DateFormattedForTHForm>,
<FormDescription>Notification Of Settlement</FormDescription>,
<FormNumber>WC 99 06 04</FormNumber>]
```

From second entry:

```
    <DisplayName>Mallesham Yamulla</DisplayName>
    <FEINOrSSN>123-45-6789</FEINOrSSN>
    <formsMaskedSSN_and_NoMaskFEIN>**-***-6789</formsMaskedSSN_and_NoMaskFEIN>
    <PrimaryAddress>
    <AddressLine1>A</AddressLine1>
    <AddressLine123>B</AddressLine123>
    <CityStateZip>ENID, OK 73703</CityStateZip>
    <Country>IND</Country>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: The xml snippets in your question aren't well formed. If they come from the same document, pleae edit your question and add a sample, well formed, xml (including any namespace declarations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(With *"list of XML beautifulsoup tag elements"* in variable `xTagList`,) you could try something like this

```py
bsParser = 'html.parser' # 'xml' # 
# xTagList = [BeautifulSoup(str(x), bsParser) for x in xTagList] # should fix some formatting
wCont_xstrs = ['\n'.join([
    str(d) for d in x.descendants if hasattr(d, 'find_all') 
    and not d.find_all() and d.get_text().strip()
]) for x in xTagList]
```

to get html/xml **string.**

---

with `bsParser = 'xml'`, `wCont_xstrs` looks like

```html
[
<DateFormattedForTHForm>07/01/2022</DateFormattedForTHForm>
<DateFormattedForTHForm>07/01/2023</DateFormattedForTHForm>
<FormDescription>Notification Of Settlement</FormDescription>
<FormNumber>WC 99 06 04</FormNumber>
,
<DisplayName>Mallesham Yamulla</DisplayName>
<FEINOrSSN>123-45-6789</FEINOrSSN>
<formsMaskedSSN_and_NoMaskFEIN>**-***-8834</formsMaskedSSN_and_NoMaskFEIN>
<AddressLine1>A</AddressLine1>
<AddressLine123>B</AddressLine123>
<CityStateZip>ENID, OK 73703</CityStateZip>
<Country>IND</Country>
]
```

[btw, if your xml had namespaces (as well formed xmls usually do), they would be lost after using xml parser. Using html parser will preserve namespaces, but there will be another issue as you will see below.]

---

with `bsParser = 'html.parser'` (and probably any other parser other than `xml`),  `wCont_xstrs` looks like

```html
[
<dateformattedforthform>07/01/2022</dateformattedforthform>
<dateformattedforthform>07/01/2023</dateformattedforthform>
<formdescription>Notification Of Settlement</formdescription>
<formnumber>WC 99 06 04</formnumber>
,
<displayname>Mallesham Yamulla</displayname>
<feinorssn>123-45-6789</feinorssn>
<formsmaskedssn_and_nomaskfein>**-***-8834</formsmaskedssn_and_nomaskfein>
<addressline1>A</addressline1>
<addressline123>B</addressline123>
<citystatezip>ENID, OK 73703</citystatezip>
<country>IND</country>
]
```

(notice how capitalization has been lost from tag names)

---

If you want a list bs4 objects, you can do something like

```py
wCont_xtags = [BeautifulSoup(x, bsParser) for x in wCont_xstrs]
```

**UNLESS** you're using `bsParser = 'xml'`, because then you need to wrap them in some tag first like

```py
wCont_xtags = [BeautifulSoup(f'<Entry>{x}</Entry>', bsParser).Entry for x in wCont_xstrs]
```